# Proving a subgroup is a basis for a space

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: V (in R) is the subspace of all 2x2 Matrixes that are upper triangular. Prove that B is a basis for V.

B=  b1= $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$b2= $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$
b3= $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

In order to prove that it's a basis we need to prove that the group B is linearly independent and that it spans V.

My questions are:

1.) Proving that the set is linearly independent seems pretty trivial.
We'll take $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in R$ such that:

$$ \alpha b_1+ \beta b_2 + \gamma b_3 =0 $$

and we get:

$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        \alpha & \beta \\
        0 & \gamma \\
        \end{bmatrix}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ which we get $\alpha= \beta=\gamma=0
$

2.) The next step is to prove that it spans V, or, knowing the dimension of V I could say that the dim(B)=3= dim(V), **but I'm unsure how to figure out the dimension of the matrices $\in$V.**

Let's say I want to check that the basis spans the set. Again  we'll take $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in R$ such that :

$\alpha b_1+ \beta b_2+ \gamma b_3 =  
\begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        0 & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

Where a,b,d $\in R$. We get:

$\alpha=a $

$\beta=b $

$\gamma=d $

Are my methods here correct for proving B is a basis for V?

TL;DR

1.) Is my way of proving linear independence correct?
2.) How do I calculate the dimension of matrices in V?
3.) Is my way of proving that B spans V correct?

Comment: Your proof of linear independence and spanning is correct. The dimension follows, because there are 3 elements in your basis. Also, fyi, subset is preferable to subgroup - the latter means something completely different in mathematics.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thanks. Studying it in a language that isn't English leads to difficulties when asking for help! So how exactly do I calculate the number of elements in V? Since there are 3 variables in a matrix that belongs in V, can I say dimV=3?

Comment: @RonaldB, Actually, by definition, $\textrm{dim}(V)$ is the number of elements in a basis for $V$. Since your basis has $3$ elements, we know that $\textrm{dim}(V)=3$.